# Why a merge instead of fast forward?

Tags: git, merge, fetch, rebase

I had just committed some new changes.
Next I did a `git fetch` then `git merge origin/master`
The `HEAD` was fast forwarded.

I continue to add 3 more commits.
Then I repeat the process `git fetch` and `git merge origin/master`.
This time, a merge was performed instead.

So, I did `git reset --soft HEAD^`

Now back to the stage before I merge.
I checked that the files changed (`git status`) are all different from my local commits.
But its saying

```
On branch master  
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,  
and have 3 and 1 different commit(s) each, respectively.
```

I believe the merge is because the branch diverged.

Why has the branch diverged?

Is it possible to do a rebase (as if doing a fast forward) if I do not want a merge?

Answer (score 2):

The branch is diverged because someone has made a change to the remote.  If you do

```
git pull --rebase
```

it will rebase your work over the divergence and give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The branch diverged because someone pushed commits to that remote branch and then you fetched them when you `git fetch`

If it's just a fast forward, you can do:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

or `git pull --rebase`, but I prefer fetching and rebasing in separated steps.

They both will fast forward and apply your local changes on the top of the branch.

Assuming you branched from and is rebasing against the same remote branch, a rebase:

- puts aside all your local commits from your last rebase or branching
- fast-forwards the branch to match the remote branch
- applies your local commits one by one. If there are conflicts, they are merged. If they can't be merged, you have to edit them manually.

So a rebase won't mess things up. When I'm following a remote branch that is being actively edited and I have a few commits, I prefer rebasing so that my changes are all at the top of the commit list.

Comment: but the merge happens randomly. most of the time it does a fast forward when i 'git merge origin/master'.
Will a rebase in this situation mess things up?

Comment: a fast-forward happens when there's nothing to be merged, otherwise it merges (so it's not random). I updated my answer to explain how a rebase would work in your case.

Comment: Ok..any idea why was a merge performed instead of fast forward? I used to think a merge was performed because the same file has different content on local and remote. But this time the files are different.

Comment: the merge happened because someone pushed content to the remote branch. It doesn't matter if the commits pushed to the remote change different files from your local commits.

Comment: Did you commit something after the previous fetch and merge?

Comment: Hm..ok..my usual workflow is commit my local changes, fetch remote, merge origin/master. That usually results in a fast-forward. Occasionally, it results in a merge. Which is what I have no idea what causes it.

Comment: Ok..I'll have to give this solution a try next time...more commits flowed in and caused some conflicts. I'll go with the safest solution that is to do a merge after resolving all the conflicts for now..will give this solution a try when I bump into the problem again.